# I tried to disable Mission Control and now Expose doesn't work

Tags: macos, mac

I tried to disable Spaces by editing Mission Control. Now, Show Deskop and show Application Hot Corners don't work.

Have restarted my computer.

Comment: How did you "edit Mission Control", exactly? What did you do?

Answer (score 0):

If you ran something like `defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool true`, you can revert it by pasting this to Terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled; killall Dock
```